# IP Client WSO2 Esb

Tags: ip, wso2, wso2-esb

I need to get IP address the client, in WSO2 Application Server I can get it by

```
getProperty('REMOTE_ADDR')
```

But I need to get the IP by WSO2 ESB (proxy). How do I get the IP by ESB?

Answer (score 4):

Try like this within the seuence of the proxy;

```
<log level="custom">
                <property name="ip address" expression="get-property('axis2','REMOTE_ADDR')"/>
            </log>
```

Check this blog post;

http://vvratha.blogspot.com/2011/11/retriving-clientiphost-within-sequence.html